# Zurb Foundation 5 Magellan not setting the active class

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb's Foundation Magellean sticky navigation and I have everything set up working well apart from the fact that it does not want to apply the active class to the menu via:

```
    $(document).foundation({
        magellan : {
           active_class: 'active',
           threshold: 0
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your initialization code is valid, here is a fiddle which shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Ka65s/2/

I would say the problem lies in your HMTL - make sure you have set the "destinations" to match the "arrivals" in your navigation.

i.e. something like this

**Navigation items:**

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
   <dl class="sub-nav">
      <dd data-magellan-arrival="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></dd>
      <dd data-magellan-arrival="about"><a href="#about">About</a></dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

**Respective content areas:**

```
<a name="home"></a>
<h3 data-magellan-destination="home">Home</h3> 
<!-- home content here -->

<a name="about"></a>
<h3 data-magellan-destination="about">About</h3>
<!-- about content here -->
```

Although, without more code form you I am just guessing (hint, hint).